# Responsive Applications

Tags: c#, responsive-design, responsive, desktop-application, windows-forms-designer

I am developing a c# application using windows forms and I wonder if it is possible to make the application responsive somehow, I've searched a lot and found that the anchor could be used but it doesn't resize things so it doesn't look responsive, is there a way that I can make c# responsive desktop applications?

For Example:

Here when I maximize the pannels they fit the window but the text will just look bad.

[Before Maximization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BC3h.png)

[After Maximization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I2py.png)

Comment: What UI Framework are you using? Windows Forms/WPF, I suggest you to put it in a tag.

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and describe what is your "not responsive" behavior. If you mean resize and keep layout, you may want to look at wpf, which has more layout related feature.

Comment: @fsbflavio I edited the post, I hope you could help me now, Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LouisGo I edited the post, I Hope you could help me now, and do you suggest wpf over windows forms ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @KhaledMohamed You did not describe what you want to achieve, provide a hand-drawn picture for your desired result might help. If you want the layout "zoom" when resize, I'll suggest wpf. Wpf has better layout control under different application size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to simply distribute the components in the maximized window, without scale the components up, I suggest you use the [TableLayoutPanel](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/tablelayoutpanel-in-C-Sharp/), instead of the Panel.

Using a TableLayoutPanel, you can divide the screen, for instance in 4 parts, 2 columns and 2 rows with 25% in each. And then distribute the components. Don't forget to set the Dock property of TableLayoutPanel to fill, or set the anchor property appropriately.

You can Stil put a [FlowLayoutPanel](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/flowlayoutpanel-in-C-Sharp/) inside the TableLayoutPanle row, doing that will provide a dynamic layout for the child controls that can be arranged horizontally or vertically.

Search for TableLayoutPanel to get some samples.

Some articles about it:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8845/FlowLayoutPanel-TableLayoutPanel-controls-Visual-S

https://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/11087_3671986_3/Changing-Layout-Dynamically-in-Windows-Forms.htm